# Make Rails look for .mobile files in subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, view-templates

I'm using the mobile fu gem to do some user-agent detection, so that I can serve either .html or .mobile extension templates depending on the client,

Now, this part works really good, but I don't like that view folders become a bit cluttered with twice the files, ie.

`app/views/profiles/show.mobile.haml`

`app/views/profiles/show.html.haml`

`app/views/profiles/edit.mobile.haml`

`app/views/profiles/edit.html.haml`

etc, etc

**what I'd like to have instead is:**

`app/views/profiles/html/show.html.haml`

`app/views/profiles/html/edit.html.haml`

And

`app/views/profiles/mobile/show.mobile.haml`

`app/views/profiles/mobile/edit.mobile.haml`

And have Rails automatically look into the correct folder/directory for files depending on the Request.
*Is this possible to do?*

Maybe this is something really easy to do, let me know if this is a behavior that comes out of the box..

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4.1 has a new built-in feature called [ActionPack Variants](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants), which detects the user-agent (like the mobile fu gem).

Basically, you can add this for example in your ApplicationController:

```
before_action :detect_device_format

private

def detect_device_format
  case request.user_agent
  when /iPad/i
    request.variant = :tablet
  when /iPhone/i
    request.variant = :phone
  when /Android/i && /mobile/i
    request.variant = :phone
  when /Android/i
    request.variant = :tablet
  when /Windows Phone/i
    request.variant = :phone
  end
end
```

Let's say you have a ProfilesController. Now you can do this:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html          # /app/views/profiles/index.html.erb
      format.html.phone    # /app/views/profiles/index.html+phone.erb
      format.html.tablet   # /app/views/profiles/index.html+tablet.erb
    end
  end
end
```

Back to your question: If you want to look for files in a different folder/directory, you can do this:

```
format.html.phone { render 'mobile/index' }   # /app/views/mobile/index.html+phone.erb
```

There is also a [good tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/action-pack-variants-in-rails-4-1) which shows how to use it.

Comment: Excellent! I'll try that, good to know Rails 4 does that out of the box!, it looks like the last line alone is the one I needed, Thanks for your kind answer, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hello, but is there a way to make rails look into a sub-folder automatically? DEPENDING on the request(format)?

Comment: The link was broken to the action pack variant info ... I edited and pointed to https://richonrails.com/articles/action-pack-variants-in-rails-4-1